# REST Partial update on multiple resources

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I have two sorts of resources, stores and items, a store can uniquely be identified by by it's ID, a store contains a number of different types of items.Items have codes to generally identify their type , for instance a conductor cable of modelA has a code of 265, an item of code 265 can exist in more than one store. 
Sample HTTP requests and their responses.

```
GET /stores/1/items
    [{
    "itemCode": 265,
    "itemDescription": "Conductor cable",
    "itemModel": "model1",
    "uom":"meter",
    "quantity": 30
    },
    {
    "itemCode": 122,
    "itemDescription": "Low-fat Milk",
    "itemModel": "model2",
    "uom":"liter",
    "quantity": 15
    }]
GET /stores/2/items
    [{
    "itemCode": 265,
    "itemDescription": "Conductor cable",
    "itemModel": "model1",
    "uom":"meter",
    "quantity": 25
    }]


GET /stores/3/items
    [{
    "itemCode": 122,
    "itemDescription": "Low-fat Milk",
    "itemModel": "model2",
    "uom":"liter",
    "quantity": 20
    }]
```

what i would like to have is a REST Api endpoint that would let the Api consumer move, say  10 meters of conductor cable of model1 from store 1 to store 2.
I know there is the option of having two PATCH HTTP requests to achieve this by updating quantities in stores 1 and 2 but I need to achieve this with a single HTTP request.

Comment: `PATCH` [can have side effects](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-2) and modify multiple resources at once, hence you can modify multiple resources with a single request

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this using HTTP PATCH then [JSON Patch - RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) should prove helpful. It allows sending multiple operations within a single request so it is possible to update multiple resources and properties at the same time. If any operation fails then the whole patch should fail as well. However within a request you have to specify the new final quantity of an item. You can't define an operation to subtract from the current value. So in order for this solution to work in a multiuser environment optimistic locking mechanism is a must. Otherwise data corruption is bound to happen.

HTTP POST is a good alternative. Moving some quantity of an item from one store to another is akin to transfering money between bank accounts. In this case I would consider creating the following endpoint: `POST /stores/item-transfer`. The request body would contain the source store/itemCode/itemQuantity and the target store. All state modifications would happen within a single transaction.

Personally I'm in favor of the POST approach however if you stick to PATCH and Java is your language then I'd suggest using the [Tomoko](https://tomoko.qubite.io) library to process RFC 6902 requests. I'm its author.